# run "docker run" from crontab

Tags: cron, docker

I try to make automated (every night at 4) backups from a postgresql database running inside a docker container.

```
#!/bin/sh

CONTAINER=`docker ps|grep name_of_container|awk '{print $1}'`
USER='postgre_user'
PASSWORD='changed'
BUDIR='/some/path/backup/'

docker run -it --link $CONTAINER:db -v $BUDIR:/backup/ -e "PGPASSWORD=$PASSWORD" pg_dump -h db -U $USER -Fc -f /backup/$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).dump
```

My crontab looks like this:

```
0 4 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

The script works fine when I execute it manually and it also get executed from cron (I tried * * * * * for debugging).

I can't figure out how to make cron and the script work together. So far I tried:

- write variables to log file
- check output from crontab (`* * * * * [...] &>cron.log`)
- check output from `docker exec [...] > output.log` in script

`$CONTAINER` contains the correct docker id when run from cron, cron.log and output.log are created but empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Can't use `docker run -it --link [...]` when running from cron - I use `docker run --link [...]` now.

Answer (score 28):

To elaborate on Martin's answer, `-it` is shorthand for `-i -t`, ie run **interactively** on **terminal (pseudo TTY)**, so it's not necessary for running in a cronjob.

If the command is suitable for automation, `-it` should be not necessary, so removing it should let you run docker from a cron job.