# Ubuntu: Cronjob for renew certbot certificates

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cron, lets-encrypt, certbot

This is how I'm renewing my Let's encrypt certificates via docker container (certbot):

```
$ sudo docker stop nginx
$ sudo docker run -it --rm -p 443:443 --name certbot -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest renew
$ sudo docker start nginx
```

Now I would like to do this as a cronjob on my Ubuntu server. For that I would add an entry in `/etc/crontab`.

But where should I put the script for renewing?

**letsencrypt.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo docker stop nginx
sudo docker run -it --rm -p 443:443 --name certbot -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt quay.io/letsencrypt/letsencrypt:latest renew
sudo docker start nginx
```

If this is correct, what would you suggest to get a note if the process is failing / is successful?

Comment: This comes a bit late but for future users: If you run the `docker run` command via `crontab` make sure you don't use `-it` (just remove it). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766116/run-docker-run-from-crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a crontab for *safe* user in a new container or your docker host and add a line for example (run a renewal once a month):

```
0 0 1 * * /path/to/letsencrypt.sh 2>> /var/log/letsencrypt.log
```

Add the user to the docker group. Users who can run Docker commands have effective root control of the system.

Only grant this privilege to trusted users.