# How can i run docker commands outside container, with cron on the host?

Tags: docker, cron

I need to automate the verification of active containers with docker ps, and send updates of containers with docker pull. So i created this script file:

```
if docker ps | grep "fairplay";then
  echo "doker fairplay ok" >> /home/ubuntu/at2.log
else
  echo "doker fairplay caido" >> /home/ubuntu/at2.log
  errdock=1
fi
```

The script works without a problem when i use manually on the terminal, but when i try with cron just don't work.

Crontab:

```
* * * * *   root    sh /home/ubuntu/at2.sh
```

The log when i run mannualy:

```
Thu Mar 25 13:33:43 -03 2021
doker fairplay ok
doker widevine ok
Thu Mar 25 13:33:44 -03 2021
```

The log when i run with cron:

```
Thu Mar 25 13:34:01 -03 2021
doker fairplay caido
doker widevine caido
Thu Mar 25 13:34:01 -03 2021
```

I don't want to run anything inside the container, i need to run the command in the cron that is on the host, so the following questions don't help [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766116/run-docker-run-from-crontab), [question 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/7nb6c8/crontab_to_run_a_docker_job/).

Comment: I recommend create a `service` on systemd so that whenever it fails, you can tell the service to restart again, and also you'll have real-time log. Have you tried that? And do you want that or you want to add it in crontab?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but i don't see how restarting would help, since when it's the cron that send the commands they all fail. I just need to know why it's not working when it's the crontab that send the command. Since it's the same command im sending on the terminal.

Comment: I created a `service` that repeat itself each 300 seconds and it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab syntax is not correct. I've tried your exact `.sh` file and I got no errors.

This is the correct one:

```
* * * * *   sh /home/ubuntu/at2.sh
```

I'm not sure why you've added `root` user or word in crontab syntax as if you run `root sh /home/ubuntu/at2.sh`, you'll get `Command 'root' not found`.

I can also recommend you add `date` variable so that you know the time it's up or down:

```
if docker ps | grep "fairplay";then
then
  echo "`date +"%D %H:%M:%S"` docker fairplay ok" >> /home/ubuntu/at2.log
else
  echo "`date +"%D %H:%M:%S"` docker fairplay caido" >> /home/ubuntu/at2.log
  errdock=1
fi
```

Comment: I'm confused about your screenshots. Please edit the question and add them there. Also share the code in code editor, please do not send screenshot of your codes.